# I am unable to use Selenium Explicit Wait if it contains jquery index

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I am using jquery index `"eq(1)"` in selenium webdriver explicit wait but it is not working.

If I remove this `eq('" + Index + "')` from the code then it works but works only for first index. Please help me out with this. Thanks

Here is the code I am trying to write and I have to use indexes.

```
var elementClickable = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("[data-uipath='" + uiPath + "'] :eq('" + Index + "')")));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `:eq()`, it's not a valid selector in Selenium. Use `:nth-child` instead. Remember to add +1 to `Index`, `:eq()` uses 0 based indexing, `:nth-child()` uses 1 based indexing

```
By.CssSelector("[data-uipath='" + uiPath + "']:nth-child(" + (Index + 1) +")")
```

Comment: I think you mean `By.CssSelector("[data-uipath='" + uiPath + "']:nth-child(" + 'Index + 1' + ")")`

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov With the `"`, without the `'`.

Answer (score 0):

try with removing the quotes around the index as given below. it may work.

```
var elementClickable = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("[data-uipath='" + uiPath + "'] :eq(" + Index + ")")));
```